# subtract a date and recovering and velocity

Tags: java, date, velocity

During my searching, I would like to have some information about my problem.

I would like to subtract three months at my current date, so typically:

```
##set($user.end = $date.format("yyyy-MM-dd", $date.date)) 
##set($user.begin = "${user.end}-03")
```

But I recover nothing.

I try that :

```
##set($R = $date.format("yyyy-MM", $date.date))
##set($query.end = $R)
##set($user.begin = "${R}-03")
#set($query.end = $date.format("yyyy-MM", $date.date))
```

But I got nothing, please if you have an advice to give me?

Ale.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First advice is to not make up your own syntax for things. :) There's no date subtraction in either Java or Velocity. You have to set the value yourself. It'd probably be better to do this in Java or in Velocity via a custom tool, but here it is in VTL anyway...

```
#set( $user.end = $date.format("yyyy-MM", $date.date) )
#set( $begin = $date.date.clone() )
#set( $month = $begin.month - 3 )
#if( $month < 0 )
  #set( $month = $month + 12 )
  #set( $begin.year = $begin.year - 1)
#end
#set( $begin.month = $month )
#set( $user.begin = $date.format("yyyy-MM", $begin) )
```

This is, of course, just using the java.util.Date API via Velocity.
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html

Answer (score 0):

Doing this kind of math with date-time is easier in [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/).

Example source code using Joda-Time 2.3 in Java 7:

```java
// © 2013 Basil Bourque. This source code may be used freely forever by anyone taking full responsibility for doing so.

org.joda.time.DateTimeZone losAngelesTimeZone = org.joda.time.DateTimeZone.forID("America/Los_Angeles");
org.joda.time.DateTime november15 = new org.joda.time.DateTime(2013, 11, 15, 18, 0, losAngelesTimeZone);
org.joda.time.DateTime threeMonthsPrior = november15.minusMonths(3);

System.out.println("november15: " + november15);
System.out.println("threeMonthsPrior: " + threeMonthsPrior);
```

When run…  (Notice we even crossed [Daylight Saving Time (DST)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time), -8 versus -7)

```
november15: 2013-11-15T18:00:00.000-08:00
threeMonthsPrior: 2013-08-15T18:00:00.000-07:00
```

About Joda-Time and related issues…

```java
// Joda-Time - The popular alternative to Sun/Oracle's notoriously bad date, time, and calendar classes bundled with Java 7 and earlier.
// http://www.joda.org/joda-time/

// Joda-Time will become outmoded by the JSR 310 Date and Time API introduced in Java 8.
// JSR 310 was inspired by Joda-Time but is not directly based on it.
// http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310

// By default, Joda-Time produces strings in the standard ISO 8601 format.
// https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601

// About Daylight Saving Time (DST): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time

// Time Zone list: http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/timezones.html
```